# Organise / Align / Snap multiple objects in a box?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am new to Illustrator so wondering if there is anyone who can help me. I have 195 flags of the world, each one a separate object. I would like to place them all in a rectangle in a neat and organised way. I have been placing them individually and nudging, but I think there is a short cut or 'Proper way'! Can anyone offer advice?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the flags for a row
2. Click vertical align center
3. Click horizontal distribute center
4. Click to make them a group (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)

Repeat all rows. Then select all rows and horizontal align them as groups and distribute them.

The tools needed are on the Align Palette:

[image]

Comment: Ryan you are an absolute Genius!! Thank you soo much. That was the quickest response I have ever had. Thank you. One further question if i may, is there a way I can select all flags (or rows of flags) and have them automatically resize to fit into the rectangle which I am trying to squeeze them all fit neatly into? Otherwise, thank you soo much for your help!

Comment: @Jim What format are the flags in and do you have the full adobe creative suite?

Comment: It was an .eps that I saved as .ai. Yes, I have the full CS6.

Comment: Hmm... you know I guess there's a few ways to do it. Its hard to say the quickest. Are they all the same size currently, just too big? Are they all different sizes? If different are they at least proportional to each other? @Jim

Comment: They are varying sizes. Each has the country name also underneath the flag (the name and flag are grouped as one). So yeah different sizes. Not to worry I could just do the math and estimate how many in a row X how many rows , and fiddle with it. No biggy. You have been incredibly helpful already!! Thanks again!